# Error ilogico al compilar un servidor http basado en sun.com.net.http en java

Tags: java

el asunto es el siguiente. Al compilar un servidor empotrado que tengo bajo la librería sun.com.net.* me da un error muy raro, siempre me anduvo bien y no he cambiado el código del cual es el siguiente :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.RequestContext;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class HttpServerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/fileupload", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(final HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            for(Entry<String, List<String>> header : t.getRequestHeaders().entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(header.getKey() + ": " + header.getValue().get(0));
            }
            DiskFileItemFactory d = new DiskFileItemFactory();      

            try {
                ServletFileUpload up = new ServletFileUpload(d);
                List<FileItem> result = up.parseRequest(new RequestContext() {

                    @Override
                    public String getCharacterEncoding() {
                        return "UTF-8";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getContentLength() {
                        return 0; //tested to work with 0 as return
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getContentType() {
                        return t.getRequestHeaders().getFirst("Content-type");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                        return t.getRequestBody();
                    }

                });
                t.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-type", "text/plain");
                t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();               
                for(FileItem fi : result) {
                    os.write(fi.getName().getBytes());
                    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
                    System.out.println("File-Item: " + fi.getFieldName() + " = " + fi.getName());
                }
                os.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

El error que me tira el compilador es el siguiente :

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
bfhsoftware/sonidoambiental/servidorhttp.java:[313,43] cannot access javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
  class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not found
1 error
```

Se puede apreciar que me pide la libreria javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest del cual no la necesito porque utilizo como ya he nombrado el servidor de la libreria com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler

En la linea que da error es la siguiente :

```
        List<FileItem> result = up.parseRequest(new RequestContext() {
```

No tiene sentido, si agrego la librería que me pide si compila pero no funciona. Por ese motivo digo que es un error ilógico.
Alguien que tenga mas conocimientos que yo sepa que pasa?
PD: anteriormente había intentado agregar un servidor de esta índole, la librería que me pide, pero borre las dependencias y todo, y me lo sigue pidiendo, he probado con dos IDE diferentes, netbeans y intellij idea comunity version, las dos me dicen el mismo error, sera que la librería se encuentra presente en algún lado y no lo se? espero que me puedan ayudar gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando la biblioteca de apache commons fileupload. Si miras las dependencias de esa biblioteca en la siguiente [URL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/dependencies.html)

Pide:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Esa dependencia por lo general la provee el servidor de aplicaciones, si no estas usando uno entonces necesitas el jar de javaEE-api.

Comment: Si colocó la dependencia, Me da error en tiempo de ejecución y sin la dependencia he intento compilar muchas veces, compila y funciona perfectamente. Es decir que la dependencia no es necesaria, se puede cambiar eso? Que evite la dependencia?

Comment: Que error en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: Busque la vuelta, reinstale jdk, borre m2 temps, todo lo que pude me pese de idea, NetBeans esta algo inestable la verdad